Can this circuit be used for an AC-DC emergency LED lamp?

Basically, this circuit is supposed to light the LED lamp from either AC or the battery.
When there is AC available the bulb will glow with the power of AC and the battery will be simultaneously charged. When AC is not there, the bulb will take power from the battery.

Is it supposed to always be on when no AC is present?

There is no current path from the battery to the LED when AC is gone.  Both diodes are reverse-biased, and there is no source of base current to turn on the transistor.


The transistor is connected such that it only conducts when the AC power is on.  The lamp will never run from the battery.
A capacitive dropper AC-DC power supply (like your circuit uses) is an electrocution hazard.  All points in the circuit must be treated like they are at 230VAC.  All parts of the circuit must be enclosed in an insulated box with no way for the user to touch any of the circuit parts when the circuit is plugged in to AC.
That 1mF capacitor is far too large.  It will allow amperes of current to flow from the AC to the lamp.
The 750 ohm and 100 ohm resistors will waste considerable power - they will get hot and need an appropriate power rating.  You shouldn't need them at all, though.
You shouldn't use a voltage divider to reduce the voltage.  That's what the series capacitor and the Zener diode are for.  The capacitor should be small enough that its impedance reduces the current to something low enough for the Zener diode and the lamp.

Get advice from an instructor if you are still attending university classes or a colleague if you are already working somewhere.
That circuit won't do what you need and it can kill you if you handle it wrong.

There is no current path from the battery to the LED when AC is gone.  Both diodes are reverse-biased, and there is no source of base current to turn on the transistor.
This is easier to discuss if the schematic has a unique reference designator for each component.
The circuit is overly complex.  You can delete both diodes, the transistor, and the base resistor.  Add a current-limiting resistor in series with the LED, and connect that string across the battery. Components to the left of the bridge will limit the total current to the LED+battery combination, and the zener sets the peak voltage.  The LED will take the current it needs based on its resistor, and the remaining current will trickle-charge the battery.
The 10 uF cap has no effect on either the peak voltage or total current.  If you don't mind the possibility of a stroboscopic effect when something moves through the LED's light, you can delete it.
The circuit has other issues.  If you are in a 220 V country (as indicated by the 50 Hz input), the two resistors to the left of the bridge are dissipating over 30 W.
The 1 mF cap is waaaaaay too large.  Its impedance at 50 Hz is only 3.2 ohms.  Did you mean to indicate a 1 uF cap?  That is a much more reasonable value, but note that if it shorts, everything else in the circuit burns up.
Is this school work?

No. When there is no AC voltage there will be no bias on the base of the transistor. Without bias the transistor will not conduct current from the battery to the lamp.
